# Do I need to know who I am performing a Pidyan HaBen upon?

Tags: pidyon-haben

A man's children were ineligible to have pidyon haben performed on them but he still wants to do the Mitzva.

He reasons that there must have been firstborn Members of the Lost Tribes who were Jewish, but did not know it.

---

Is it effective to redeem a deceased person?
Does he need to have a specific **named** person in mind?
Can he algorithmically designate a person: (eg: "The nth most recently born Gadite firstborn)

Here is a source for the Beit Din appointing an agent to perform a pidyon haben.
https://aish.com/pidyon-haben-no-father-non-jewish-father/

Comment: "... _but he still wants to do the Mitzva_". To what end? If he performs it as someone else's agent, does he get any merit for the Mitzva itself?

Comment: The page you link to also says: "_Even with all the above_ [the procedure of redeeming a firstborn through a Beit Din's agent], _there are opinions that a third party cannot fulfill the obligation for the boy_".

Comment: Rather than seek out members of lost tribes, there are undoubtedly millions of kosher Jews in the US who have never even heard of a pidian haBen. I doubt it would be difficult to find one or to convince him to come to a big banquet in his honor.

Comment: The banquet is not part of the mitzvah. A living reform new still has his own chiyiv

Comment: @ClintEastwood it has the din of a seudat mitzvah

Comment: Source for performing a pidyon haben for a deceased child is Meiri end of Pesahim and Rema on YD 205:12. The sources speak in the context of the father however (not a delegatee). They also do not express an opinion about whether there is an expiration on its performance. As regards children of lost tribes: their existence is hypothetical. It is impossible for us to know if any such children that fit the bill ever existed. Maybe statistically likely (depending on the vantage) but not certain. I don't see how a miswa (esp w blessing) could be performed over an existence not known to exist.